How can I create an affordance for both seeking to a word, and also looking up up a word?
I'm building a language-learning application involving reading texts aligned to audio. The words currently being spoken in the audio are underlined.

There are two different actions that I want to enable the user to do:

Tap on a word, and it will seek the audio to the time where that word is spoken. For example, if the user wants to hear something repeated that they didn't quite catch the first time, they can tap the part of the text the want to start from, and the audio will play starting from there.
Tap on a word they don't understand, and it will show a modal window with the definition of the word / translation into their native language.

Unfortunately, these two goals actions contradict each other. If I just want to seek to a particular time in the text, I don't want to be distracted by a window showing up with the definition. If I want to just look up the meaning of a word, I just want the audio to pause while I read it, I don't usually want it to seek to that word.
I've thought about doing something like "single click for seek, double click for look up", but I'm concerned about the discoverability of an action that requires a double click.
Are there any other alternatives for ways to make it possible for the user to be able to both seek to words and look up the meaning of words?

Try leading with a tap to view definition, and offer an in-context button to jump to recording.
I'm not totally clear on the full context of use (and constraints you may have), but a few thoughts, and I'll update my answer if my assumptions are off.
Instead of trying to overload the interaction, try teaching the user they can navigate the audio player once the word is tapped. Prioritize definition first, and location in audio as a secondary action.
In the enclosed sketch, I've put some instruction text telling them what happens when they tap a word.

Allow the user to view the selection in context if possible
Below the transcript, there's a reserved area for where the definition and audio controls appear.
This way you don't have a popup obscuring the text, and they can see how the word appears in context of the sentence. This will help them see things like the subject verb order.
The definition section displays the word, but also informs the user how many times the selected word appears, with a control to view in the transcript.

I also like this approach. And another thing to consider is the order of importance for user actions. Actions that are more significant and used most often should be the primary actions.

You can add a context menu with both options to choose when selecting a word as explained in this article: How to Create Actions for Selected Text With the Selection API

